# How to replace an existing product's url with a new product

Tags: magento2, product, url-rewrite, url-key

I am duplicating a product, disabling the old one and want to set the url of the new product to replace the old product.

```
$duplicateParent = $this->productCopier->copy($oldproduct);  
$oldproduct->setUrlKey($existingUrlKey . '-old');
$oldproduct->setSku($existingSku . '-old');            
$oldproduct->setVisibility(1);

$duplicateParent->setUrlKey($existingUrlKey);

$oldproduct->save();
$duplicateParent->save();
```

It's throwing an error because the URL exists already, even though I've changed the URL of the old product.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Product URL stored in URL Rewrite `url_rewrite` table.

> Admin -> Marketing -> SEO&Search ->URL Rewrites

In the list search the old URL from `Request Path` if you found delete that.

Now you can free from this kind of error.

Comment: Hi, in this case it's not practical to do it manually as there are thousands of products which we will be duplicating. I was hoping that changing the url of the old product would also change the existing url rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

To replace an existing product's URL with a new product in Magento 2, you can follow these steps:

1. Make new product
2. Redirect Old URLs
   "Marketing" > "SEO & Search" > "URL Rewrites"

"Old URL" -> to "New URL"

3. Clear Cache

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't solve my issue

Comment: to redirect the URLs, you have only this solution other than you will need to buy extension